# TypeScript: is it possible to create a mapped union type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to combine the "mapped types" and "union types" features to create an expression that takes the following interface as an input:

```ts
interface AwaActionTypes {
  CLICKLEFT: 'CL';
  CLICKRIGHT: 'CR';
  SCROLL: 'S';
  ZOOM: 'Z';
  RESIZE: 'R';
  KEYBOARDENTER: 'KE';
  KEYBOARDSPACE: 'KS';
  OTHER: 'O';
}
```

And produces a type that is the equivalent of the following union type alias:

```ts
type AwaActionType: 'CL' | 'CR' | 'S' | 'Z' | 'R' | 'KE' | 'KS' | 'O';
```

I tried using combinations of `keyof`, `|`, etc. Didn't land on something that worked. Didn't see anything in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a combination of keyof and [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html)

```
type AwaActionType = AwaActionTypes[keyof AwaActionTypes];
```

Comment: is it possible to do this with enums?

Comment: You can get keys of enum with `keyof typeof Animals`